# PHP Undefined Variable in Json Encode

Tags: php

```
<?php
require 'config.php';
$db = new connect();
$students = $db->select("students","ORDER BY students_id ASC");
if( $students != null ){
foreach ($students as $student) {
$student['error'] = '';
$output[] = $student;
}}else{
$student['error'] = 'No students...';
$output[] = $student;
}
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

if the database is empty i have error. Notice: Undefined variable: output

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you initialise `$output` as an empty array first,

```
$db = new connect();
$output = array();
$students = $db->select("students","ORDER BY students_id ASC");
```

Your code only ever initialises $output if the foreach loop runs, which it won't with no results from the database

Comment: Not working. Now results = just -------> []